# check if the first element of a string is positive integer

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I need to check if the first element of a string is positive integer in C#.
is there a smart Way to do this?
Fx

```
string str = "2001";
if (str.First() == isANumber) {
...                                
}
```

Comment: What *precisely* do you mean the "first element of a string"? the first character? or...?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid he gave the code snippet, what else do you expect?

Comment: "First Element" is not defined. We can't answer the question accurately without an accurate definition of "first element".

Comment: @VladL That isn't something he has tried, it is a suggestion. He is asking for code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
string s = "1sdfa";
bool isDigit = char.IsDigit(s[0]);
```

Also, if you wanted additional checks on string, you could do them like this:

```
bool isDigit = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && char.IsDigit(s[0]);
```

Comment: That returns true for "1.1" which is clearly not a positive *integer* (if "first element" doesn't just mean "first character")

Comment: I'd use `bool isDigit = s.Length > 0 && char.IsDigit(s[0]);` if it's indeed the first char he meant.

Comment: Yeah, I'm waiting for the OP to clarify... Since "positive integer" is an odd term to use if you're just talking about a single character.

Answer (score 3):

I believe if no sign then it is positive? So just check whether the first sybmol is not `"-"`.

EDIT: As Mark noted in a comment below - it may depend on a culture which is used.

Comment: depends a bit on culture, though ;p

Comment: @daryal: then `"first element of a string"` even not a number?

Comment: @sll then checking whether the first element is not "-" is not enough?

Answer (score 2):

Can use [Char.IsDigit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t641e58.aspx)

```
Char.IsDigit(str[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [char.IsDigit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y5kahff.aspx) method to check if the first character is a digit or not.

```
if(char.IsDigit(str[0]))
    Console.WriteLine("Starting character is positive digit");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Starting character is not a digit");
```

Its better if you can check the length of the string before accessing its index `0`

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`Char.IsDigit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh.aspx) method.

> Indicates whether the specified Unicode character is categorized as a
>   decimal digit.

Like;

```
string str = "2001";
if (Char.IsDigit(str[0]))
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Positive digit");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Not digit");
}
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/fVOybO).

Comment: @MatthewWatson OP wants to see if the first char of string is positive digit or not. That's the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Char.IsDigit(str.First()))
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "2001";

if (char.IsDigit(str.First())
{
   if(Convert.toInt32(str.First().ToString()) >= 0)
   {
     // positive integer
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hello u can use this...

```
string something = "some string";
bool isDigit = char.IsDigit(something[0]);
```